# Measurable functions.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $f(x,y)$ be nonnegative Borel function on $\mathbb{R^2}$.Prove that $\psi(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)d\mu(y) $ is also Borel function($\mu $ is symbol for Lebesgue measure).
My attempt:
()
$f(x,y) \geq 0$ so there is sequence of positive sample functions $(s_n) $ such that $s_n(x,y) \rightarrow f(x,y) $ as $  n \rightarrow +\infty$.Now I can use Lebesgue Monotone theorem $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int _{\mathbb{R}}s_n(x,y)d\mu(y) = \psi(x)$.If i show that $\int _{\mathbb{R}}s_n(x,y)d\mu(y)$is measurable $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ i am done but i don't know how to do that.

Any answer or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the proof of Tonnelli's Theorem. You can find a proof in any book which has Fubini/Tonelly Theorem.

Comment: Can you give me a good reference for it .

Comment: Rudin's RCA. Look at 'sections' of measurable sets and their measurability (which can be found in the proof of Fubini's Theorem).

Comment: I wanted different proof not given in book ,can you help me?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117828/measurable-function-characteristic-function-of-measuable-set @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @Mark I don't think there is any proof which avoids things like Montone Class Theorem or Dynkin systems Theorem. What is your  motivation for avoiding Monotone Class Theorem ?

Comment: I knew proof with MCT  but   I thought there must be other solution because question didn't seem hard to me.